# Terraform -- how to refer to variables inside an interpolated value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In a terraform .tf file, I have a variable, `cluster` defined as so:

```
variable "cluster" {
    type = "string"
    default = "test_cluster"
}
```

I use the variable to define an AWS VPC.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "${var.cluster}_vpc" {
    # ... configuration ...
}
```

My problem is when I want to associate an AWS DHCP Option set using the id of the previously defined AWS VPC -- the one named `${var.cluster}_vpc`. A logical view of what I'm trying to do (which won't work because Terraform doesn't support nested interpolation) is:

```
resource "aws_dhcp_options_association" "${var.cluster}_dhcp_assoc" {
    "vpc_id" = "${{var.cluster}_vpc.id}"
}
```

How do I refer to `${some_cluster_vpc.id}` when `some_cluster` is actually defined by `${var.cluster}`?

OK. I think that if I add the VPC itself as a module, I can pass in a `${cluster}` and return a `${vpc_id}` to be used by the various components that need that value.

**EDIT:**  Setting up vpc.tf as a module was the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do this in terraform

```
resource "aws_vpc" "${var.cluster}_vpc" {
```

Yes you want to create a module and pass in the values to the module to do what you are looking to do easily